# Different behaviour when using ELEMENTS XSINIL on SQL 2005 and SQL 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I have a legacy problem between SQL 2005 (9.0.5057) and SQL 2012 (11.0.3128). When I run the following sample SQL query on SQL 2005 and then SQL 2012 I get different results:

```
select
  0 'test1/@old', null 'test1',
  null 'test2/@old', 2 'test2',
  2 'test3/@old', 2 'test3',
  null 'test4/@old', null 'test4'
FOR XML PATH('Data'), ELEMENTS XSINIL
```

For SQL 2005 the result is:

```
<Data xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <test1 old="0" />
  <test2>2</test2>
  <test3 old="2">2</test3>
  <test4 xsi:nil="true" />
</Data>
```

For SQL 2012 the result is:

```
<Data xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <test1 old="0" xsi:nil="true" />
  <test2>2</test2>
  <test3 old="2">2</test3>
  <test4 xsi:nil="true" />
</Data>
```

Test1 is where the problem is occurring. The behavior for SQL 2012 is correct but I am struggling to find either a patch or work around for this in SQL 2005.

I ran the same test on SQL Server 2008 R2 (10.50.2500) but get the SQL 2005 result.

Am I missing something somewhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Am I missing something somewhere?

No, this appears to be a bug in SQL Server that is fixed in SQL Server 2012, perhaps in SP1.

[SQLXML: for xml path(), elements xsinil: xsi:nil="true" attribute is missing when other attribute is generated on the same element](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/476828/sqlxml-for-xml-path-elements-xsinil-xsi-nil-true-attribute-is-missing-when-other-attribute-is-generated-on-the-same-element)

> I am struggling to find either a patch or work around for this in SQL
>   2005.

A workaround that might be acceptable for you is to add the missing attributes where they should be.

Store the result of your query in a XML variable and then use [modify() Method (xml Data Type)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187093.aspx) and [insert (XML DML)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175466.aspx).

It is only possible to add one value at a time so it has to be done in a loop using [exist() Method (xml Data Type)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189869.aspx) where you check for empty nodes that is missing the `xsi:nil` attribute.

```sql
declare @X xml

set @X = (
         select
           0 'test1/@old', null 'test1',
           null 'test2/@old', 2 'test2',
           2 'test3/@old', 2 'test3',
           null 'test4/@old', null 'test4'
         for xml path('Data'), elements xsinil
         )

while @X.exist('//*[empty(text()) and empty(*) and empty(@xsi:nil)]') = 1
  set @X.modify('declare namespace xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";
                 insert (attribute xsi:nil {"true"}) into 
                   (//*[empty(text()) and empty(*) and empty(@xsi:nil)])[1]')

select @X
```

`//*` gives you all nodes in the XML.
The brackets `[]` are used for the predicate.
`empty(text())` checks for text in the node.
`empty(*)` checks for sub-nodes.
`empty(@xsi:nil)` search for the presence of the `xsi:nil` attribute.

Comment: This is exactly what I ended up doing. Not pretty but it works. Do you know if the modify method has any significant performance knocks. The stored procedure that does this work is called numerous times every minute.

Comment: @RichardDorman No, I have not heard anything specific that would be really bad other than the general opinion that XML is slow in SQL Server. If this is too slow then I guess you could do something in SQL Server CLR.